# Ajedrez en Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

De la siguiente manera podemos resolver un ajedrez en java script:[JJFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/AntonioVladimir/wrk6nxud/1/)

Comment: Primero, necesitarás trabajar con un bucle más grande: `(let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {`, después comprobarás si el índice está a 0 -> `if(i === 0)` y ahí puedes añadir un div diferente con el índice dentro. Lo mismo en el otro bucle para las letras, para ello puedes usar [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromcharcode.asp) para representar la letra a partir de su [código ascii](http://sticksandstones.kstrom.com/appen.html) y si empiezas en 65, será la A. Solo tienes que sumarle el índice actual e irás incrementando el valor y representando diferentes letras A,B,C...

Comment: En lugar de editar, deberías comentar en la respuesta si necesitas aclaraciones o marcarla como aceptada si te sirvió.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crea un arreglo para el contenido de los encabezados, una letra por cada columna. Agrega primero esa fila y, después, agregas la celda con número al inicio de cada fila:

```js
const board = document.getElementById("board");
// Crear arreglo de letras (columnas), el primero debe ir vacío
const letters = ['', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'];

// Crear fila para encabezados
let row = document.createElement('div');
// Recorrer arreglo para mostrar letra en cada columna
letters.forEach(letter => {
    let cell = document.createElement('div');
    cell.className = 'number';
    cell.innerText = letter;
    row.appendChild(cell);
});
board.appendChild(row);

for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement("div");
    // Mostrar número de fila antes de las celdas
    let cell = document.createElement('div');
    cell.className = 'number';
    cell.innerText = (i + 1);
    row.appendChild(cell);
    // Ciclo para mostrar celdas
    for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        let cell = document.createElement("div");
        if (i % 2 == j % 2) { cell.className = "white"; }
        else { cell.className = "black"; }
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    board.appendChild(row);
}
```

```css
#board, #board > div {
    display:table-row;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#board .black, #board .white, #board .number {
    display: table-cell;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px #000 solid;
}
#board .number {
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px transparent solid;
}
#board .black {
    background:#000;
}
#board .white {
    background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Comment: Triby esta perfecto y me sirvió un montón, pero las intenba hacer indexada en las primeras celdas o por ambos sitios con lo cual perfecto, me sirvió, pero no he conseguido imprementarlo.