# php tablero de ajedrez

Tags: php

Tablero de ajedrez

Necesito hacer que una tabla se rellene como un tablero de ajedrez (cambiar los colores), pero no se qué condición podría ponerle en el `if` que haga que los colores se ponga como un tablero de ajedrez

```
<?php


  $ren=$_POST['renglon'];
  $col=$_POST['columna'];

  echo "<center><table border = '1'  width= '50%'>";
        for ($r=0; $r <$ren ; $r++) { 
            echo "<tr>";
                for ($c=0; $c<$col ; $c++) { 



                  if() {/* no se que ponerle alli para que rellene la tabla como un tablero de ajedrez*/
                    echo"<img src='imagenes1/n.jpg' width= '10%'>";
                  }else{
                    echo "<td>&nbsp </td>";

                  }
                }     
                

            echo "</tr>";
        
        }
  echo "</table></center>";

?>
```

Comment: A qué te refieres como "tablero de ajedrez"? Con las piezas de ajedrez? Alternando colores?

Comment: Alterar los colores de la tabla

Comment: Tal vez [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/413054/ajedrez-en-javascript/413060#413060) en Javascript te pueda servir como guía. Inténtalo y, si algo falla, edita la pregunta para mostrar tu código y poder ayudarte sobre algo concreto.

Comment: Pares un color.. impares otro color... ;)

Comment: En resumen esto $r%2 == $c%2, pero te aconsejo leer a fondo el link puesto por @Triby